# failed to load class 'org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder'

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

I created a jar file with all the dependencies, and I implemented the logging using slf4j + logback. Thus I have a `logback.xml` file defined for all the loggers. However when I run the jar it gave me this message:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I dont see any logging happening. After I unzip the jar file, I can see the org.slf4j folder. I don't know why this is not working.

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder (the link in the message):

> This error is reported when the org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
>   class could not be loaded into memory. This happens when no
>   appropriate SLF4J binding could be found on the class path. Placing
>   one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar, slf4j-simple.jar,
>   slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class
>   path should solve the problem. SINCE 1.6.0 As of SLF4J version 1.6, in
>   the absence of a binding, SLF4J will default to a no-operation (NOP)
>   logger implementation. You can download SLF4J bindings from the
>   project download page.

In other words, you need a slf4j backend in your classpath, e.g. logback.

Answer (score 2):

It seems `logback-classic.jar` is missing from classpath.

Take a look at http://slf4j.org/manual.html#swapping.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a scala project? If yes then adding the below dependency will help. It worked for me.

```
 "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.7.12"
```

Comment: Doesn't solve it for my scala project. Does the version matter?